# Gulp-git clone in specific folder location. Cloned to 'undefined' folder

Tags: git, gulp

How do I do clone and put it in specific location?

```
 var git = require('gulp-git'); 
// Clone a remote repo
 gulp.task('clone', function(){
 git.clone('https://git-location', './apps/');
});
```

I've been looking at documentation but I cannot find any.

Below are the output, after running the task

```
[11:17:05] Starting 'clone'...
[11:17:05] Finished 'clone' after 5.76 ms
[11:17:48]  Cloning into 'undefined'...
```

When I run the task it is copying the file into **undefined** folder. Obviously, I am doing something wrong. Can anybody point it out to me?

Comment: Additional information: The end result that I am looking for is to have the git copied to apps folder.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Thanks to S.Lacey (one of the publishers of gulp-git) for prompt response to my question. Below is the right format.

```
git.clone("https://git-location",{cwd: "./apps/"});
```